# Why does apt-get abort by itself, as though I'd pressed 'N'?

Tags: command-line, apt, error-handling

On Ubuntu 14.04, when I try to install an app or even just do:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I always end up with this message at the end:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

I didn't type anything, it just automatically aborts.

Can you guys help me?

=======[ Edit #1  Aug 12 ]=======
Here I have copied the entire terminal texts.
I have run 2 command here, the:
sudo apt-get update and then after I get the result I run the
sudo apt-get upgrade

Here's the copied texts from terminal:

```
franzbiely@Franz-Gizmo:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                         
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Sources                        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                   
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [59.7 kB]               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en_PH              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_PH                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_PH                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [59.7 kB]              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [290 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_PH
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_PH
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_PH                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [5,820 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [177 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [7,381 B]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [286 kB]     
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [5,820 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [178 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [7,598 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en         
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [87.0 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en         
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [125 kB]  
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [43.4 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,147 B]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [122 kB]   
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [43.3 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,402 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en          
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_PH                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_PH              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_PH              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_PH                
Fetched 1,502 kB in 3min 15s (7,672 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
franzbiely@Franz-Gizmo:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas linux-headers-generic linux-signed-generic
  linux-signed-image-generic unity-settings-daemon
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-libc-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 784 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
franzbiely@Franz-Gizmo:~$
```

=======[/ end edit ]=============

Comment: What happens if you type `y`?

Comment: @Eliah yeah, try actually giving it y when it asks [Y/n]. I normally suggest that they do `sudo apt-get update | pastebinit` and give us the link, as it can be quite a long output...

Comment: After I type y, it just says command not found since i'm typing y in ~$

Comment: Yeah @tim, the issue is that I'm aborted already even though I haven't type anything so I'm in the ($ command line now).

Comment: @EliahKagan I'll try to copy everything and paste it here when I get back to my computer at home.

Comment: No i mean instead of just pressing enter, type `y` then press enter when it asks [Y/n]

Comment: Hi @EliahKagan have already updated the question with the terminal full texts.

Comment: @Tim yeah I hope I can do that, but it says Abort already even though I haven't pressed y or anything.. please check the updated question above. :)

Comment: oh. That's very strange...

Comment: i had this issue too in elementary os when trying to install something, what was happening was that a wrong command was copied and pasted. restarting the terminal and writing the command instead of pasting it did it

Answer (score 42):

apt-get aborts when it wants interactive confirmation but can't read input from stdin.

For example, anyone (with pending upgrades) can reproduce this behavior by redirecting /dev/null to stdin:

```
skath@tahiti:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade < /dev/null
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libcgmanager0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 29.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
skath@tahiti:~$
```

This leads to the next question, what's taking over stdin when you're calling `sudo apt-get upgrade`? That's a trickier question and might involve your sudo configuration or the terminal or shell you're using to invoke the command...

Or, if you just need a workaround, you can pass `-y` to `apt-get` to skip the prompt: `sudo apt-get -y upgrade`

Comment: Same issue, I'd rather know what is eating the input. This happens in Yakuake. Other terminals such as KDE's Konsole or mlterm functions as usual.

Comment: I ran into this too (on Debian, I know, this is Ask Ubuntu, but maybe it will still be helpful...) and have no idea why it happened, but I opened a new tab in my terminal emulator application, and the problem went away.

Comment: It's like a sin, one of those big ones. It disappeared after a purported update.

Comment: I see, that would explain why it happened to me after using `wildmidi`, which is apparently trying to capture some input to change volume, etc. while playing midi, but didn't release correctly after segfault or something.

Answer (score 11):

my problem was that I tried to run several commands at once by copy-pasting them into console

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install build-essential
...
```

Calling each command separately solved my problem

Comment: There can also be a 'hidden' carriage return between two package names. When I removed this eveything installed with a one line command e.g. `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libdb-dev libdb++-dev`

Comment: @undersound thank you! You should add this as an answer. I had that problem when installing a single package, but I _had_ copied it from a webpage & took the carriage return along with it. apt-get still gave me the prompt but (I think) took my input as `\rY` rather than `Y` so aborted

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem on 18.04.2.  `update`, `update`, and `dist-upgrade` worked fine; `install`, failed with an abort.  *Yes*, using `-y` worked.

However, I found that there was a problem in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and that by restoring it to the default that came with the distribution (you can find your version online easily enough), that completely solved the problem.

I suspect that one of the alternate third party library scripts that was adding its own repository made a mistake.

I'd recommend making a backup copy, try replacing the file, ensuring the ownership and permissions are the same as the original, and then doing a `sudo apt update`, then try your install.

I haven't had any problems since.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem trying to install php. I changed `sudo apt-get install` to `sudo apt install` and that worked for me. That may help you or not

Answer (score 2):

## Try to run the following, and if helped, tell me in the comments what did you do before just running `apt-get`:

```
perl -MFcntl -e 'fcntl STDIN, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN, F_GETFL, 0) & ~O_NONBLOCK'
```

Explanation: `apt-get` (and many other programs) expects STDIN to be in blocking mode. Some rouge programs leave it non-blocking. Curiosity made me ask you to find out, document and maybe file a bug with those rogue programs. Other way to solve: run `bash` and type `exit` to return to the current bash. Bash will set things correctly upon entering.

FYI, the problem can be induced by running:

```
perl -MFcntl -e 'fcntl STDIN, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK'
```

Comment: +1 just for the comment about bash;exit

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened for me when I copied and pasted the command from the website (docker.com, particularly). Look like there are invisible encoded characters on the site that prevent `apt-get` to process. What I did to solve this is to paste the command to the browser address bar first, so the browser eliminates all the weird characters and then, copied it again from the address bar and pasted it again to the terminal. The browser address bar is the best tool to remove those characters, IMO (worked for me most of the time)