# Can't install Oracle Java on Lubuntu 17.04 - Install aborts itself

Tags: lubuntu, java, oracle

I'm trying to install Oracle's Java from this PPA

```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

But after i enter the third command this happens.

```
    lubuntu-hs@lubuntuhs-Satellite-C55D-A:~$ sudo apt-get install 
    oracle-java8-installer
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      gsfonts-x11 java-common libxfont1 oracle-java8-set-default 
    xfonts-encodings
      xfonts-utils
    Suggested packages:
    binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-
    core
      ttf-kochi-gothic | ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho
      | ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      gsfonts-x11 java-common libxfont1 oracle-java8-installer
      oracle-java8-set-default xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils
    0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 797 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 1,579 kB of additional disk space will be 
    used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Abort.
```

No matter what I do at the Y/N point, any action will cause my terminal to spit out

```
    Abort.
```

**Edit:** Installing via Synaptic didn't present the same issue. To anyone who has the same issue, use Synaptic instead.

Comment: Try `yes |  sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does apt-get abort by itself, as though I'd pressed 'N'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509852/why-does-apt-get-abort-by-itself-as-though-id-pressed-n)

Comment: Also try installing the **"Suggested packages:"** `binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-core`

Comment: I believe it is expecting an upper-case Y instead of a lower-case y, try an upper-case Y.

Comment: Typing a lowercase case Y works on mine and also simple pressing the Enter key which selects the option which is capitalized.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer`?