# APT goes straight to "Abort" when prompting for confirmation

Tags: apt, bash

I'm trying to remove some packages which are not being used, but every time I run `sudo apt-get autoremove`, it asks for a yes/no confirmation and then terminates.

Yesterday I switched the shells from oh my Zsh to Bash and I've been facing these issues since then. I also observed awkward behaviour in Vim; it automatically executes something and prints a message

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I am using Ubuntu 17.10. Here is the output from `autoremove`

```
$ sudo apt autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
libjemalloc1 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libmsgpackc2 libtermkey1 libunibilium0 libvterm0 neovim-runtime xsel
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 9 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 18.1 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
$
```

I get the same result when `sudo apt upgrade` prompt for confirmation. Passing the `-y` flag works around the problem.

What could be broken here and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Try purging them one at a time, starting with `sudo apt purge libjemalloc1`. That'll at least help to narrow down the problem.

Comment: actually the command gets terminated automatically

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?  Individually, for all the packages?

Comment: yes @RonJohn, it gets terminated automatically for all

Comment: Hmm.  Try `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: i already tried that and it ran successfully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74483/discussion-between-utkarsh-mani-tripathi-and-ronjohn).

Comment: I think there's a "always yes" option for apt-get, see it's man, but something sounds really broken. Using only Ubuntu sources, or different ones?

Comment: @Xen2050 only Ubuntu sources

Comment: Related: [Why does apt-get abort by itself, as though I'd pressed 'N'?](//askubuntu.com/q/509852)

Comment: What procedure did you follow to switch your shell to Bash?

Comment: i commented `source $ZSH/.oh-my-zsh` in `~/.zshrc` and the ran `source ~/.bashrc` and then removed all the files related to zsh in `/etc/zsh*` and at some other places

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue when doing an apt upgrade which was aborting just after asking for Y/N confirmation.

> sudo apt upgrade

I tried my usual workaround and tried to upgrade on a new terminal. Surprisingly, it worked. I realized, it was a problem with that particular terminal.
After researching on why this happened, I found this:

[Why does apt-get abort by itself, as though I'd pressed 'N'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509852/why-does-apt-get-abort-by-itself-as-though-id-pressed-n/1012392)

This says that the apt command aborts if it is unable to take input from stdin for an interactive command.

So one can use `sudo apt -y upgrade` to skip asking for user confirmation as a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow your shell is not recognized as an [interactive shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch), which has probably something to do with your shell change.

As the hotfix, you can force `apt` to remove the packages with the `--yes` switch

```
apt-get --purge --yes autoremove
```

`--purge` is optinal.

Comment: That's not a [hotfix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotfix), but rather a [workaround](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaround). Plus, OP already stated exactly this solution in the question…

Comment: "Somehow your shell is not recognized as an interactive shell" - that's a good theory! Can you ask OP to check that? (Ask them to run `echo $-` and see whether the output includes `i`) The real fix would be reconfiguring the shell in that case

Comment: @Zanna I am experiencing the same problem with apt-get and ssh-keygen and my $- is `himBHs`